# Is there any extra NullPointerException risk in this code?

Tags: java, inner-classes

I have an anonymous class need to use self reference when it is created. My business code can be simplified as the following code, I know this code:

```
final Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Math.random()>0.5){
            runnable.run();
        }
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

cannot compile because the value of runnable inside inner class is captured before the whole statement completes. And I don't want to use a static or a class property to hold runnable because I don't want to forget removing unnecessary variables when this part is removed. So I modify to become this:

```
final Runnable[] runnable={null};
runnable[0]=new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Math.random()>0.5){
            runnable[0].run();
        }
    }
};
runnable[0].run();
```

Is there any extra NullPointerException risk compared with normal object creation like this:

```
Runnable runnable=new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
};
runnable.run();
```

?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If all you want to do is call `runnable.run()` from in instance method invoked on `runnable()`, you can just call `run()`. This code is weird, though. Each invocation basically has a 50/50 chance at getting that much closer to a stack overflow, and it doesn't accomplish anything else.

Comment: Anyway, no, it won't NPE. But the behavior is deterministic, do you could just give it a try and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you are trying to catch should almost certainly be done using a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to put that inside of a method, it's not valid Java because you would be accessing `runnable` before it is initialized. So this won't compile:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(Math.random() > 0.5) {
                    runnable.run(); // <-- compilation error here
                }
            }
        };
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

But if you mean to create it at the class level like this:

```
public class Main {
    final static Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(Math.random()>0.5){
                runnable.run();
            }
        }
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Then it will compile and will *never* throw a `NullPointerException` because what is captured is not the value of the reference but the actual field (The bytecode will access `this.runnable.run()` each time).

Nonetheless as others pointed, this can be done with a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you can also replace your inner class(s) by `Lambda expression`.

```
Runnable runnable = ()->{
            if(Math.random()>.5) {
                //TODO Code
            }
        };
```